# Is there an easy way to pick specific observations from column out of a data frame for a function to use? Like a filter in excel pivot table?

Tags: r, input, filter, pivot-table

I have a function below from the package `gapminder` to run an analysis. I need to pick two continents out of the five available.

```
library(gapminder)

part3 <- gapminder
continent1 <- subset(part3, continent == "Asia")
continent2 <- subset(part3, continent =="Africa")
#As I'm going to t-test I need two factors - picking two continents
part3c <- rbind(continent1, continent1)
```

**Question** Is there a way for the user to pick continents for the analysis e.g., some code that says "pick two from the five available" that allows for the analysis to be run with different combinations?

Something like getting the output from filtering data in an excel pivot table or do I need to code in the continents each time - as above?

Comment: Are you looking for `sample(unique(part3c$country), 2)`? Or do you want all combinations? Or one country from Asia and the other from Africa? The question is not very clear.

Comment: @RuiBarradas no, but thank you. I want it to pick the continents, as that level is ok for me. However , will ```sample(unique(part3c$continent), 2)```  do that for me? If yes, how do i know which ones it picked?

Comment: Your code can be simplified down to 1 line, you can go straight from `part3c  <- subset(gapminder, continent %in% c("Asia", "Africa"))`. If you code your analysis as a function, then you can easily replicate it on different subsets - or use a loop to do it an all subsets. But if you want a button to click, there's not an easy way to do it. Once you get the hang of it, simple `shiny` apps don't take **too** much effort for  a nice GUI, but it's definitely not quick and simple.

Comment: Thank you again @GregorThomas no, not shiny, not yet anyway. Thanks for the coding tip. I'm starting to see the ```%in%``` tunnel method a bit clearer

Comment: Sorry, I missed the sentence where you say it's continents you want. As for how to know which ones it picked, you will know because in that case that's `sample`'s return value.

Comment: @RuiBarradas ```part3d <- sample(unique(part3c$continent), 2)``` produces values not a dataframe - how do i get the dataframe output?

Comment: `twocont <- sample(unique(part3c$continent), 2); i<-gapminder$continent %in% twocont; part3[i, ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?
Function `combn` returns the combinations of a vector, in the case below 2 by 2 and applies a function to each of them. The function `test_fun` first makes sure the groups are of the same size, then runs the t-test.

In the example call, I test equality of `lifeExp` by continent but any other column can be tested.

```
test_fun <- function(X, col){
  cols <- c(col, "continent")
  n <- min(nrow(X[[1]]), nrow(X[[2]]))
  Y <- lapply(X, \(y) {
    if(nrow(y) > n)
      y[sample(nrow(y), n), cols]
    else y[cols]
  })
  Y <- do.call(rbind, Y)
  t.test(get(col) ~ continent, Y)
  
}

sp_part3 <- split(part3, part3$continent)

combn(sp_part3, 2, test_fun, simplify = FALSE, col = "lifeExp")
```